# How to get checkBox readOnly state in Gxt 3.1.1 like there is isReadOnly() method in gxt 3.0.0?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am trying to implement something like the below code in my projeect using Gxt 3.1.1 :

```
CheckBox checkBx = new CheckBox();
checkBx.setReadOnly(False);

System.out.println(checkBx.isReadOnly());
```

While this snippet will ru nwell on Gxt 3.0.0 but with 3.1.1 its showing the last line as unsupported. Also there is no method to get ReadOnly state. How can I implement any method for such functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an API change from 3.0.3 (See https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/announcements/release_notes.html):

> Backwards incompatible - CheckBox and Radio no longer support setting
>   the readOnly attribute (only supported by text and passwords inputs)

You can use `setEnabled()` and `isEnabled()` instead.

Comment: Sorry I didnt verify earlier. But `checkBx.getCell().isReadOnly()` is only going to get ReadOnly state of the cell which has its own getter and setter. My query is regarding the checkbox element as a whole. Any ideas for getting its readOnlyState